# BadPaddingExeception whilst decrypting AES256

Tags: java, encryption, java-me, aes

Currently having issues with the decryption of an AES hash.

When i encrypt using AES256 i get the following result (After base64 encoding)

```
07sKQfb9dN86XAMxFmVKHQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
```

I believe my issue is with the AAAAAAAA etc. for some reason I think anyway the padding isn't being removed during decryption.

My code

```
public String encrypt(String key, String initVector, String value) throws Exception {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, initVector.getBytes().length);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, key.getBytes().length, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] encrypted = new byte[32];

        cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(), 0, value.getBytes().length, encrypted, 0);

        System.out.println("Base64: " + Base64.encode(encrypted));
        System.out.println("Hex: " + bytesToHex(encrypted));

        return Base64.encode(encrypted);
}

public String decrypt(String key, String initVector, String encrypted) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, initVector.getBytes().length);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, key.getBytes().length, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] decrypted = new byte[64];
        cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encrypted), 0, Base64.decode(encrypted).length, decrypted, 0);

        return new String(decrypted);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

What i am expecting when i encode base64 `07sKQfb9dN86XAMxFmVKHQ=`

String i am encrypting: Test
Secret key: `password12345678password12345678`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    byte[] decrypted = new byte[64];
```

you created a 64 byte array but the decrypted value may be shorter (Java doesn't use zero string terminator unlike C does). So you should not make assumption over the parameter length

try using

```
encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
```

and

```
decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encrypted));
```

Comment: He also made the same mistake in his encrypt method.

Comment: One of my problems is that in J2ME I can't do decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encrypted)); Only method available is cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(), 0, value.getBytes().length, encrypted, 0); which returns an integer

Comment: Ok so if i make your edits and make the size of the buffer dynamic by doing         byte[] encrypted = new byte[value.getBytes().length + (16 - (value.getBytes().length % 16))];
 That sorts that issue but doesn't fix the problem i was originally having

Comment: @jay-young Oh, I forgot about javame. Nevertheless - your `doFinal` method should return integer (output length) so you could trim/copy/encode only bytes which are needed.